# IS Javascript event "onafterprint" Working in chrome 71.0.3578.80

Tags: javascript

I used `window.onafterprint` javascript event and its working fine before chrome update but when i updated my chrome to 71.0.3578.80, it stop working and all functionality goes down. Can any body suggest me the alternative of this event. I want to detect after print event.

```
var afterPrint = function () {
        var hide_if_empty = $('.hide-if-empty');
        for(var i = 0; i < hide_if_empty.length; i++){
                $(hide_if_empty[i]).parent('div').show();
        }

        var hide_duplicator = $('.duplicator');
        for(var i = 0; i < hide_duplicator.length; i++){
            if($(hide_duplicator[i]).attr('id') != 'duplicator') {
                $(hide_duplicator[i]).hide();
            }
        }
    };
    window.onafterprint = afterPrint;
```

Comment: According to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=beforeafterprint), `Printing Events` are still supported in chrome 71-73. Please post your code, the problem might be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Its not working for me too, I moved the logic to line after printing.

Comment: @AhmadMaleki reference code is added please review it.

Comment: @ShaheerNaseer I don't identify any problems in your javascript alone, please add a working snippet with also your html. But to assure you that there is no problem with `onafterprint`, open a new tab in your browser > open console > copy this simple code `window.onafterprint = function(){alert('wow after print!')}` and press enter. now open print dialog box and close it. you should see the alert.

Comment: for me, window.beforepirnt is not listening in chrome v71.0.3578.80